# windows forms hide panel and show button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel on my windows forms inside of which I have two text boxes and a button for user login. On successful login i hide the panel and show another button called Process Cases. Everything works the way I want.

```
myPanel.Visible = false;
btnProcessCases.Visible=true;
```

The Process Cases button is laid out below the panel. Upon hiding I would like the button to occupy the position that the panel earlier occupied. How do I do that?
Right now its positioned below the panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
btnProcessCases.Location = myPanel.Location;
btnProcessCases.Size = myPanel.Size;
myPanel.Visible = false;
btnProcessCases.Visible=true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following:

```
    btnProcessCases.Left = myPanel.Left;
    btnProcessCases.Top = myPanel.Top;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `Dock` property of `myPanel` to Top then put your button in another panel (buttonPanel) and Dock it to Top. Then toggling the visibility of `myPanel` will cause the panel containing the button to nicely slide to the top. No nasty resetting of the physical location of buttons or panels and no nasty design concerns with overlapping controls. The Dock property will soon become your best friend.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the `Location` property of the button to the location of the `myPanel` panel:

```
btnProcessCases.Location = myPanel.Location;
btnProcessCases.Visible=true;
myPanel.Visible = false;
```